# How do I get Windows 7 to see Ubuntu 10.10 shares?

Tags: windows-7, samba, ubuntu-10.10

My Windows 7 computer can't see the folders I shared on Ubuntu laptop. The other way around works fine and I can open files shared in Windows from Ubuntu.

I have already tried to install and configure Samba.

Anything I need to check to get things working?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install and configure Samba on your Ubuntu machine, so that any Windows Users can get to see your shares. Double check the settins and permissions.

Comment: I did that already

Comment: Anything else I can try?

Comment: I'm afraid not - my experience with Ubuntu is very limited.